Invalid app info in play_integrity_token when using phone login although everything is setup
Trying to use phone otp login in my android Java app, I set up the SHA-1 and SHA-256 using ./gradlew signingReport and I downloaded and added the google-services.json to the app directory, still I can't send any code and get:
2024-06-11 00:33:46.740 23101-23101 FirebaseAuth            edu.birzeit.gradproject              D  Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +97059999999, error - This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ] 
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid app info in play_integrity_token
I have a real phone number in the my actual case the number here is chnaged for the question.
I've also made sure that the right package name is there
I tried using keytool -list -v \-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore' to get the SHA-1 and 256 and got the same results.
I also geneated a keystore and used
 keytool -list -v -keystore <your_keystore_path> -alias <your_alias_name> -storepass <your_store_password> -keypass <your_key_password>
and also got the same problem
